# wpf Как передать контекст данных из DialogHost?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Определил класс DialogHost.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Pearlbook_Core
{  
    partial class DialogHost:UC_MainWindow
    {
        public Pearlphonebook Pearlphonebook { get; private set; }
        public DialogHost(Pearlphonebook p)
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
            Pearlphonebook = p;
            this.DataContext = Pearlphonebook;
        }
    }
}
```

Код обработчика событий:

```
private void ItemCreate_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var result = AddDialog.IsOpen = true;
    DialogHost dialog = new DialogHost(new Pearlphonebook());
    Pearlphonebook pearlphonebook = dialog.Pearlphonebook;

    db.pearlphonebooks.Add(pearlphonebook);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Диалог открывается, вношу в его `TextBox`'ы данные, но в таблицу добавляется пустая строка.

Что не правильно делаю? Как правильно передать данные из `TextBox`'ов в таблицу с помощью контекста данных?

Comment: У вас происходит изменение данных свойства Pearlphonebook, и, я предполагаю, на него у вас и Binding в вашем TextBox в Xaml. Но класс DialogHost не наследуется от интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged, и не сообщает об изменении значения свойства. Необходимо унаследоваться от INotifyPropertyChanged и изменить get и set в свойстве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение на свой вопрос
**CodeBehind:**

```
private async void ItemCreate_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                var pearlphonebook = new Pearlphonebook();
                db.pearlphonebooks.Add(pearlphonebook);
                db.SaveChanges();
                await DialogHost.Show(pearlphonebook);
            }
```

**MVVM**

```
public RelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addCommand ??
                    (addCommand = new RelayCommand(async (o) =>
                    {
                        var pearlphonebook = new Pearlphonebook();
                        db.pearlphonebooks.Add(pearlphonebook);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        await MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost.Show(pearlphonebook);
                    }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ужасное решение. А судя по тому, что вы написали `MVVM` - вы явно не знаете что это, ибо вы как минимум обращаетесь к контролам через код. Также не пойму зачем вы дублируете код, он же идентичные вещи выполняет...

Comment: Я новичок в C# WPF. Поэтому и был задан данный вопрос. Можно было бы и пример с вашей стороны оставить, как было бы грамотнее. Тем не менее пусть реализация ужасна, программа работает. А на данном этапе уже неплохо!

Comment: Я вам советую посмотреть примеры по MVVM, понять для чего он создан и как с ним работать. Писать ответ я лично не вижу смысла по одной простой причине - для меня ваш вопрос непонятен, ибо пустая строка может быть из за кучи вариантов и только вам известно все, что в коде. Переписывать по правилам MVVM тоже я не вижу смысла, ибо там скорей всего тоже придется переписывать много чего (о чем я даже не знаю, ибо опять же, код ваш), а переписав ваш ответ - вам мало что это даст. Так что только в ваших руках понятие MVVM, я сейчас увы, лишь могу сказать что вы нарушили базовые правила этого подхода.

Comment: Мое решение вполне работает и добавляет данные в строки как нужно.
Мне непонятно ваше утверждение, что я не понимаю для чего MVVM. Делал я по примерам с metanit. Команды реализованы в AppViewModel согласно правилам и вызываются они в xaml через Command{Binding Название команды}

Comment: Простой вопрос - если вы скопируете весь XAML в отдельный, чистый проект, без c# кода, у вас проект запустится? Если да, то ок, ваш код не нарушает MVVM, если же нет - значит ваш View слой тесно связан с ViewModel, что является нарушением MVVM. Судя по обработчику `void ItemCreate_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e` - все же в XAML вы ссылаетесь на ViewModel, которая не должна знать совершенно нечего про View. Но опять же, я не вижу всей картины, по этому без понятия что у вас там, может это у вас `Behavior`, кто знает)

Comment: Все я понял. Я просто в ответе хотел показать 2 варианта. Первый вариант без mvvm через обработчик событий. А второй уже с mvvm через команды в appviewmodel. А вы подумали что эти два варианта из одного проекта)) Это не так.